# VW Passat white smoke coming from exhaust

Tags: vw, coolant, smoke, passat

My VW Passat started giving out white smoke from the exhaust while in motion. One of the hoses of coolant system had swollen up on and was replaced.

There is a smell of gas was coming from inside cabin so mechanic had replaced the valve gasket, but there was still white smoke. Now the yellow engine light on dashboard was flickering.

Today I found the coolant level was at the minimum in reservoir. When I started the car there was white smoke from the exhaust straight away.

What's wrong with my car?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) Which engine do you have? I've edited your question to make it more readable, if you have any problems feel free to change it :)

Comment: From what you described, it seems like a failed head gasket, but the smell of gas has me questioning that. Does the white smoke smell like gasoline? Or antifreeze (kind of sweet)?

Answer (score 1):

you are most likely to have a blown head gasket. White smokes occur when water mixes with your fuel. With one of your coolant hoses having undergone repairs, I highly guess the problem is with your head gaskets. Fix this asap else, serious overheating problems could occur.
Best.